# How to create user and give access to a database

Tags: oracle, oracle10g

How do I create a new user and give him access to ORCL database in oracle 10 g (TOAD/SQL Developer/SQL Plus). I tried to do this in SQL Developer, but when I try to login with the newly created user, it says `"Insufficient privileges"`

Comment: `create user my_user identified by my_password` then `grant dba to my_user`; p.s. the question is well documented

Comment: @are where did you define which database you are giving access to this user?

Comment: @WasimQadir Are you sure you mean database and not a schema? Database is isolation at physical level, schema is just a logical separation. Users and schema are synonymous. A user cannot access another database unless you have created the required database link and let the user do so.

Comment: please don't grant DBA to a user. start with the minimum privs required, such as CONNECT and go from there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you might be confused between **database** and **schema**. Also, remember, **user** and **schema** are synonymous. A schema contains the set of objects owned by the user. Other than that, they are similar.

What you need to do is:

```
SQL> create user test_new identified by test_new;

User created.

SQL> grant create session to test_new;

Grant succeeded.

SQL> conn test_new/test_new@pdborcl;
Connected.
SQL> show user
USER is "TEST_NEW"
```

Above example shows how to **create a user**, **grant create session privilege** just to make sure user is at least able to connect. You would obviously need more privileges for the user to do further tasks.

Usually, you would create **roles** and grant required privileges to the roles. And then assign the role to a user.

---

**UPDATE**

Per the comments, OP is unable to connect via **SQL*Developer**.

> but when I try to login into the SQLDeveloper i get error message Insufficient privileges when Role is set to SysDba

You should not use SYSDBA for a normal user other than SYS.

> ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied

Either your username or the password is incorrect. In **SQL*Developer** you need to correctly provide the

1. username
2. password
3. hostname
4. port
5. service_name

Test the connection, if it is success, start using it.

Comment: this works fine in SQLPLUS/Command prompt but when I try to login into the SQLDeveloper i get error message `Insufficient privileges` when Role is set to `SysDba`, but role is set to `Default` it says `ORA-01017: invalid username/password; logon denied`